# Could not load file or assembly 32 bit assembly

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, dll

I have been searching and trying for many hours. I am having '**System.BadImageFormatException**' when running my WCF service hosted on IIS 10.0 from 64-bit client application.
- I tried to set `Enable 32 bit applications` = **true** .
- I checked that **target CPU = Any CPU** .
- I double checked on the **applicationHost.config** file on the `<ApplicationPools>` section and make sure that `Enable 32 bit applications = true` .
 All these attempts with same result, the same error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DBConnNET4, Version=1.0.34.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60d47e8c3d6f39e7' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

When debugging, I am getting the exception inside class from the referenced library, exactly here:

```
Public Class BusinessObject

Private Function Invoke() 
     Dim obj As new BusinessObject()
     obj.ctrlQueryRun()
End Function

  Private Function ctrlQueryRun() As Short
        Try
            '*** the exception occurs at this line, GetAllItems() is function in the same class         
       If Me.GetAllItems() = cERROR Then Return cERROR


            '' Some code Here

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return cERROR
        End Try
        Return cSUCCESS
    End Function

End Class
```

All the solutions I found on the Internet were telling to do the previous attempts, any other suggestions? Is there any thing I forgot to check? Many thanks in advance for anyone helping or trying to help.

Comment: Perhaps the library is 32-bit? If so, I think you application must run as 32-bit as well. Try setting Platform to x86.

Comment: Or you should use the 64-bit version of the library

Comment: @JerryM yes, the library is 32 bit , I tried to change target CPU to x86 but I got the same exception

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How could I have 64-bit version of the library?

Comment: Check the vendor's site? Or your installation? What is `DBConnNET4` ?

Comment: DBConnNet4 is dll library that have classes and some functions, I took the library as it from my manager and used it in my application, but she didn't tell me that I can have another version

Comment: @panagiotis any suggestions?  :(